# Which rx5700xt's driver is stable with blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

Every time I try to use GPU compute in cycle, Blender crash, I don't even have to render, the moment I switch from CPU to GPU in Blender's cycle, the viewport would say "Loading render kernels", and then after a while, it crashes. And when I do try to render without entering render mode in the viewport, it would also say loading render kernels and then crash.

I have seen people benchmarking cycle render with rx5700xt online, so I assume that this is a driver issues. I would like to know which version of Radeon software and drivers should I install for the gpu to work in Blender?

This is my current system:
CPU: Ryzen 7 2700x;
GPU: MSI Rx5700xt Mech OC;
Ram: 2x16gb;
OS: win 10,
Blender version: 2.83.7;
Radeon's Software version: 20.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try blender 2.82a, it may obsolete but run properly for me
i am using rx 5600 xt, 20.9.1, windows 10 20h2
the version above that crashes, or use radeon prorender